# Play video at certain pre defined coordinates

Tags: video, divide

I'm trying to play a video at certain coordinates and to be of a certain size, but haven't been able to find anything online, could someone please help me out..
Ex: want a certain video to play on the left upper corner and height and width also pre-defined..
Can that be done one any media play that exists? I'm trying to play many videos at a time without them overlapping each other etc..

Comment: If u arent bothered by old browsers u can use the HTML5 `<video>`(http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/) tag

Comment: is there any way of doing it using a software like media play etc?